# SSRS hyperlink to report prompting for values

Tags: reporting-services, hyperlink, parameters, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have main report which is using Register report in hyperlink.

So whenever a user clicks on Register hyperlink it should show particular register which is displayed in report.

Register report using 2 parameters - Year and Register

When I click on Register in main report it prompts me to select register from dropdown list instead of showing data directly.

What can be done to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both the reports are in the same project, you can use a Drillthrough Action. This'll let you create a link between the two without needing to construct the URL. In the **Properties** of an object, under **Action**, choose **Go To Report**. This will let you select what should be used for each parameter, with either static values or from your data.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207031(v=sql.105).aspx

If they're in completely separate locations, you can add the parameter at the end of the URL you're using. Point to the report server of your Register report, and add `&param_name:param_value` to the end for each parameter.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms155391(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can add the paramters in the URL by adding "&rp:ParameterName=ParmaterValue" for each parameter needed.

e.g.

https://MyReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=MyReport.rdl&rp:Param1=True&rp:param2=False